# Logging for multi=threaded server component

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging

I have a multi-threaded sever application that I'm writing in C++ and I need to implement a good and fairly efficient logging system.  By efficient I mean that whatever amount of logging is configured, the application shouldn't ever come to a grinding halt.  So preferably there is some thread that is dedicated to writing it's log files.

I want to log each request that the server component handles in it's own file, having a rotation system that removes files older then some threshold. A request is handled by 2 threads, one that does some conversion work and the a worker-thread that is part of thread pool (BOOST threadpool) that does all the other actions (database gets, calculations, etc).  So the logging need be threadsafe and I have to be able to configure it for levels and let each Logger class instance (my own logger that implements some library) accept a new file name.  So that each new Logger instance is created for a specific request.

My ultimate question is:  Which logging library allows me to have a new Log file for each request and allows me to configure log levels?  (IE: error, warning, critical, etc)

Or should I implement everything myself?  (no logging is not an option)

I have looked at Boost::Logging v2 and since the main logger object, that holds all state (levels, files) is global, I cannot change the files for each request.

I have looked at templog.org and this I can't even get to compile.  No matter what I include or which references I set, it can never find the templog namespace or any of its classes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Apache [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html). It a great logging library !

Comment: thats a .NET log library, I'm after C++ libraries

Comment: It well exists for .net but for Java, c++ and PHP as well.  Look better ;-)

Comment: I renamed your link to log4cxx instead of log4net. I agree, it's a great library. I've used it in several projects.